# some android devices can not get video thumbnail,The video was shot with the iPhone

Tags: android, ios, video, thumbnails, mediametadataretriever

I use the native android sdk way to get online video thumbnail,Source code is as follows:

```
private Bitmap showVideoThumbnail(Boolean isUrlPath, String videoPath)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mmRetriever = null;
    try
    {
        if (StringUtil.isEmpty(videoPath))
        {
            return null;
        }

        mmRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        if (isUrlPath)
        {
            mmRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
        } else
        {
            mmRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        }

        bitmap = mmRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        if (mmRetriever != null)
        {
            mmRetriever.release();
            mmRetriever = null;
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

However, in some android device, this method can not get iPhone device captured video thumbnail.
so,i want to what is the problem,please,thank you

Comment: Can you please include details of what happens when you try to read an iPhone-generated video? Is an error thrown?

Comment: no error thrown,iPhone video file has been uploaded to the server,use this code "mmRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());",but "bitmap = mmRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);",this bitmap is null